# VBA: Escape double quotes around a single character within a string

Tags: string, ms-access, vba, escaping

I am facing a problem that I hope I can get some help in this forum. I am retrieving values from a SQL Server data-table, loading them into an array to then use the array to add the items to a drop-down-list.

The problem that I have is that one of the values contains double quotes around one of the characters of the string.

This is the value: "A" Side Music, LLC

Because of the double quotes around the A, that value is not included in the drop-down-list, all other values are present.

The code that I have tried is this piece:

```
    For intRecord = 0 To UBound(arrRecords, 2)

        Name.AddItem (Chr(34) & arrRecords(0, intRecord) & Chr(34))

    Next intRecord
```

Is there any way someone could help me figure how to work around this problem?

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

I am including a screen shot of a watch I added to demonstrate that the value is being retrieved.

[image]

Comment: If the quotation marks are already in the string you received from the table, you should only need to use `Name.AddItem arrRecords(0, intRecord)`

Comment: When I use only that part, then the only character I see is the A, and without the double quotes.

Comment: Is `Name` the name of your drop-down list?  What sort of drop-down list is it?  (E.g. a ComboBox?  a ListBox?  In Excel itself or on a user form?  If in Excel, is it an ActiveX control or a Forms control?)  And have you confirmed that `arrRecords(0, intRecord)` actually contains the string `"A" Side Music, LLC`?

Comment: Sorry, I was also assuming that this is Excel-vba.  But I now see that the tags are "vba" (in which case my comments might make sense, although "Excel" might need to be replaced with "Access" or "Word" or "Powerpoint") but it is also tagged as "vb6" which means this isn't VBA and none of my comments will be meaningful.  Which language are you using?

Comment: Name is the name of the combo-box. I am on MS Access, and this is a form. I added a screen shot of a watch to show that the value is being passed. This is VBA, my bad, I removed VB6 from the tags.

Comment: OK - I have just been playing with Access forms, and they do behave strangely compared to the Excel listboxes I am used to.  I will continue playing and see what I can come up with, but hopefully someone else with more experience will answer.

Comment: I hope so. Thank you.

Comment: Try doubling up the quotes before adding to the list `Name.AddItem Replace(arrRecords(0, intRecord), """", """""") ` per 
  http://allenbrowne.com/casu-17.html

Comment: Why can't Access behave like all other Office applications !!?!?!?!?  Anyway, enough ranting, single-quotation marks are the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSAccess needs single-quotation marks around the string when entering information into a ListBox:

```
Name.AddItem "'" & arrRecords(0, intRecord) & "'"
```